# How to assign subdomain location to subpath in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, dns, reverse, strapi

I'm setting up reverse proxy settings of two apps hosted on the same Digital Ocean droplet. Reverse proxied by Nginx.

- A pure front-end app (`localhost:3000`) on `example.com`
- A Strapi API (`localhost:1337`) on `api.example.com`
- The Strapi admin dashboard (`localhost:1337/admin`) on `admin.example.com`

For the moment, i tried to basically have a `admin.example.com` file in my `/sites-available/` folder which have a `location` binded to `localhost:1337/admin`

// nginx/sites-available/admin.francoisglevarec.com

server {
        listen 80;

```
    root /var/www/admin.francoisglevarec.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name admin.francoisglevarec.com www.admin.francoisglevarec.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/admin;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

}

The problem is that every request are returning `404` and the app is crashing. If i remove the `/admin` from `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/admin` it takes me obviously to the wrong location but everything works when i navigate to `admin.example.com/admin`. But the idea here is to get rid of the `/admin`.

Thank you everyone